# chartjs-trendline implement a dashed line?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, trendline

using chartjs and chartjs-trendline plugin. I am attempting to satisfy the ui by implementing a dashed trendline. However this is proving to be a significant challenge to me. I have suggestions ranging from borderDash[], to lineDash[] to just using dashed.. and none are working. my current code is as such:

```
 this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: value.map(x => x.key),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Trend",
              showLine:false,
              lineDash:[5,5],
              data: value.map(x => x.value),
              pointBorderColor: this.trendcolour,
              pointBackgroundColor: this.trendcolour,
              borderColor: this.trendcolour,
              backgroundColor: this.trendcolour,            
              trendlineLinear: {
                style: this.trendcolour,
                lineStyle: "solid",
                lineDash:[5,5],
                width: 2,
                options:{
                  lineDash:[5,5],
                  borderDash: [10,10]
                }
              },
            } as any
          ]
        },
        plugins:[chartTrendline]
       });
```

produces:
[image]

Is there a way, using this plugin.. to achieve a dashed line as opposed to dotted or solid? Thank you for any advice you might have.

Comment: The plugin clearly has only [`dotted` and `solid`](https://github.com/Makanz/chartjs-plugin-trendline#configuration) as options. If you really want some other dash than the default `dotted`, you should find a more or less elegant way to hack into or even change the well-written and easily readable [source code](https://github.com/Makanz/chartjs-plugin-trendline/blob/v2.0.5/src/chartjs-plugin-trendline.js#L140) **with all the disadvantages of doing that**, like having to repeat/verify the procedure whenever a new release is published or being tied to a fixed version.

Comment: Thanks. That is a lot of vitriol in the morning for me. I was just asking if it was possible. No need to be angry about it.

Comment: I wasn't being angry about it at all. I'm sorry if you took my (possibly too formal) language as vitriol. I actually said that it *is* possible, (and that I can see some almost elegant but hacky ways)  but, to cover my bases, I had to point out that there are disadvantages.